# Alternative to using triggers to automatically send email for each calendar event created

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I am trying to automate certain parts of my workflow for scheduling clients with Google Calendar. I've successfully managed to capture new/edited/deleted events in Google Apps Script using a trigger which detects changes and `Calendar.event.list` to sync those changes with a spreadsheet.

I create a new row, or edit an existing one, in my spreadsheet of all the clients. What I desire to do is three days before the appointment with the client, automatically generate a custom email with all of their details, to send them as a reminder regarding the appointment.

My plan was every time a new row was created in the Spreadsheet (when a new Calendar event was created), was to make a new email trigger. That trigger would execute code to create an email, with all of the clients info.

```js
function createEmailTrigger(event) {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);  // Don't care about time

  // Create Email Trigger three days before
  const sendDaysBefore = 3;
  var daysBefore = new Date(event.start);
  daysBefore.setDate(daysBefore.getDate() - sendDaysBefore);

  var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
    .timeBased()
    .at(daysBefore)
    .create();

  associateEventWithTrigger(trigger.getUniqueId(), event);

  return trigger.getUniqueId();
}
```

`associateEventWithTrigger` connects the trigger id with the Calendar event. `sendEmail` would then create a new email with all of the client's info, which came from the Calendar event. When the trigger is executed, it deletes the trigger since it won't be used again.

All of this was working fine, as I was testing one Calendar event at a time. However, once I decided to sync all of this year's Calendar events, the script very quickly threw this error:

```
Exception: This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added.
```

Apparently you can [only have 20 triggers per user/script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). This is very inconvenient, as I was expecting to create hundreds of triggers.

Therefore, I need to rethink how to go about doing this. Any suggestions? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Proposed workaround

This script is designed to be run on a **time-driven trigger** that runs **daily**.

```js
function sendReminderEmails() {
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let range = sheet.getDataRange();
  let values = range.getValues();

  // removing headers
  values.shift()

  values.forEach(row => {
    let name = row[0]
    let email = row[1]
    let date = row[2]

    // Date object representing time now
    let now = new Date();

    // helper variables
    let second = 1000;
    let minute = second * 60;
    let hour = minute * 60;
    let day = hour * 24;

    // gets time to appointment in milliseconds
    let timeToApp = date.getTime() - now.getTime()

    if (timeToApp > 2 * day && timeToApp < 3 * day) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(
        email,
        "Remember Your Appointment",
        "Hello " + name + ",\nYou have an appointment coming up soon."
      )
    }
  })
}
```

This is based on a sample spreadsheet like this:

[image]

So you would need to adapt it to your particular format.

#### Script walkthrough

- It is based on the [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
- If your dates are stored as formatted dates in your spreadsheet, when you `getValues`, Apps Script will automatically pass them as Date object. Alternatively you can cast them as Date objects in Apps Script if needed.
- The script starts off by getting all the values in the target sheet.
- It initialized a new Date object that represents the time now.
- It then goes through each row of the target sheet and gets a value for how long until the appointment.
- If the value is between 2 days and 3 days, then an email is sent.

Comment: I ended up using a similar approach. I was going to post it myself, but you beat me to it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I Think you could make an script to search events every day , events that are 3 days ahead , select then and send email. So it will be just one script that will be triggeres every day, using the date trigger mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).